# How to style container widgets like a pagelist or splitview without pitfals (see details) - CSS

Tags: javascript, css, widget

I'm making a JS widget library and I need to style a container widget like a pagelist or a splitview and I can't get around certain pitfals.

- I can't use the " " combinator for styling inner elements of the widget because that accidentaly touches the contained widgets too.
- To fix that, I'm using the ">" combinator but that couples the styling to the DOM structure for no good reason and creates a lot of repetition.
- To avoid that I'd have to set state classes (like `.invalid`) to all inner elements of the widget, not just to the widget itself (outermost element) and that's also repetitive and error-prone. To avoid *that*, I could set the .invalid class to the innermost element and then I can use `:has(.invalid)` on any outer element. That means also setting tabindex=0 to the innermost element so that I can use `:has(:focus-visible)` on any outer element. But those are hacks and sometimes there is no single innermost element.
- Those hacks create specificity bugs.

If anyone has written a widget library with container widgets, are there any good ideas to work around these problems?

Would-be solutions that don't exist in CSS:

- a CSS combinator similar to " " that would not match further down a subtree after a first match in that subtree.
- a pseudo-selector that matches a selector in an element's parent chain like eg. `:ancestor-has(.invalid)`.